# Iterating through a list checking if the input of an user is inside the list

Tags: python, arrays, list, iteration

I have a problem! I'm trying to iterate trhough a list, checking if a value it is inside or not, if it's inside proceed to the next step, if it not, repeat input till user input an element inside of that list

Next, I'll put the code I have, please, some of the list are done for other purposes! The one I'm using for this is FoodAvaiable.

```
DictFood = {"pasta":["spaghetti"], "meat":["beef of deer", "sasuage"], "vegetables":["chips", "letucce"], "condiment":["sugar", "salt"], "fruit":["apple", "orange"], "sweet":["chocolate"], "drink":["beer", "water"]}
TypeFood = ["pasta", "fruit", "meat", "vegetables", "condiment", "sweet", "drink"]
DictValue = {"orange":1, "spaghetti":12, "salt":0.2, "chocolate":2, "beef of deer":1, "beer":0.3, "water":0.5, "fish":3, "chips":2, "sugar":0.2, "bread":2, "apple":1, "letucce":1, "sasuage":3}
FoodAvaiable = ["orange", "spaghetti", "salt", "chocolate", "beef of deer", "beer", "water", "fish", "chips", "sugar", "bread", "apple", "letucce", "sasuage"]
x = True

def food_type():
    global user_option_f
    print("What do you want to buy?")
    print(FoodAvaiable)
    user_option_f = input()
    while x == True:
        if user_option_f == FoodAvaiable[0]: #here I have my doubt!! I've tried using "or" to add "FoodAvaibale[1]" and so on, and I got a infinite loop, I've tried "range(len(FoodAvaiable))" didn't worked too
            x == False
            print("You choose {}!".format(user_option_f))
        elif user_option_f != FoodAvaiable:
            print("You choose an element which is not avaiable! Please select one of the list")
            print(FoodAvaiable)
            print("Choose one avaiable")
            input()
    return user_option_f

food_type()
```

How do I make my user_input_f iterate  through the elements of the list, checking if it's inside or not.

Sorry if this have been asked before, I've searched a lot didn't find anything that would help me. Thanks beforehand

Comment: Instead of `user_option_f != FoodAvaiable` you should try `user_option_f not in FoodAvaiable`

Comment: `if some_item not in some_list:` will do exactly what you expect...

Comment: I'll try this! But this is not what I actually want it to, but probably solved my next problem so, thanks ^^

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using a nested for loop, but the proper way is to just us the 'in' operator.

```
while True:
    user_input = input('Food: ')
    if user_input in FoodAvailable:
        return user_input
    else:
        print('Choose one of {}'.format(', '.join(FoodAvailable)))
```

Comment: In addition to this, you probably want `FoodAvailable` to be a `set`, not a `list` (for faster `___ in FoodAvailable` checks)

Comment: @NiemaMoshiri Thanks, I'll make a research about this! But since the list is shot, and I don't want to actually expand it, just checking, don't think I need it, but for further projects I'll take a look

Answer (score 0):

I managed with the help of some answer to fix the code (Thanks to @UnoriginalNick and @StephenRauch)

```
DictFood = {"pasta":["spaghetti"], "meat":["beef of deer", "sasuage"], "vegetables":["chips", "letucce"], "condiment":["sugar", "salt"], "fruit":["apple", "orange"], "sweet":["chocolate"], "drink":["beer", "water"]}
TypeFood = ["pasta", "fruit", "meat", "vegetables", "condiment", "sweet", "drink"]
DictValue = {"orange":1, "spaghetti":12, "salt":0.2, "chocolate":2, "beef of deer":1, "beer":0.3, "water":0.5, "fish":3, "chips":2, "sugar":0.2, "bread":2, "apple":1, "letucce":1, "sasuage":3}
FoodAvaiable = ["orange", "spaghetti", "salt", "chocolate", "beef of deer", "beer", "water", "fish", "chips", "sugar", "bread", "apple", "letucce", "sasuage"]


def food_type():
    x = True
    global user_option_f
    print("What do you want to buy?")
    print(FoodAvaiable)
    while x == True:
        user_option_f = input()
        if user_option_f in FoodAvaiable:
            x = False
            print("You choose {}!".format(user_option_f))
        elif user_option_f not in FoodAvaiable:
            print("You choose an element which is not avaiable! Please select one of the list")
            print(FoodAvaiable)
            print("Choose one avaiable")
            input()
    return user_option_f

food_type()
```

Getting the input outside of the definition gave me an error, so I end up writing it inside the def and making some tweak on the elif, maybe I should use else instead, but since seems stable this way, I'll keep it